# Must I generate an additional salt, even though password_hash() already provides a salt?

Tags: php, cryptography, salt, bcrypt, php-password-hash

In using PHP's native password_hash() function, must (or should) I generate my own salt even though (to my understanding), it can already create a salt as seen here in this example (provided by http://www.php.net):

```
 <?php
/**
 * Note that the salt here is randomly generated.
 * Never use a static salt or one that is not randomly generated.
 *
 * For the VAST majority of use-cases, let password_hash generate the salt randomly for you
 */
$options = [
   'cost' => 11,
'salt' => mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM),
];
echo password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options)."\n";
?>
```

Currently I've been hashing using sha512 and generating a 38,500 character salt. (I wasn't sure if character count really mattered, so I tried anyways… it seems to have worked, as in allowing me to register and login users successfully, but I know not the whole security flaws of this)
Something like this:

```
  <?php
  $Salt =  str_repeat(hash("sha512", uniqid(time())), 40);
  ?>
```

Pretty odd, but when it comes to cryptography I have a lot to learn. 
(here's a link to one of the salts https://shrib.com/F7lB9Ycf)
Now if I were to add an additional salt (if you were to say yes, salt again), then how would I append the salt in using password_verify()?

Thanks in advance to any who could help!

Comment: `password_hash()` generates its own salt. No need to salt again.

Comment: Ok… so in your opinion would it make it less secure if I were to salt again?

Comment: to much salt is bad for you

Comment: If you want to explore the relative merits of different salting scenarios then [security.se] would be a better place to ask. You could probably improve security by repeatedly salting and hashing a password, but each iteration has a cost.The question really is _'Is it secure enough?'_

Comment: haha, yes bad for your heart ^.^… but it would even lengthen the password.

Comment: Ok, I really appreciate you pointing me there! I didn't know they even had that.

Comment: Is the 'cost' the amount of resources used by the server?

Comment: Cost is related to the "delay", helping to prevent timing attacks on passwords (among other things)

Comment: Ok, so basically sleep(), but not pausing the action, just delaying the action in prevention of brute force attacks?

Comment: The password is actually 38,520 characters long… Is that long enough though?

Comment: AFAIK the bcrypt as implemented by php ignores everything in the salt after the first 16 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *not* generate your own salt, because the function [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) does it as best as possible, using the random source of the operating system. In other words, you won't be able to generate a better salt, though you could do it worse.

```
// Leave out a salt in the options
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 11));
```

There is absolutely no advantage of generating a salt with 38500 characters. Depending on how the salt is added, it could even reduce security, when you use an algorithm with a maximum length for passwords (as BCrypt does). Usually a salt is about 20 bytes.

A salt should protect you from rainbow-table attacks. A rainbow-table would have to be built for exactly this salt, because brute-forcing a random 20+ password is impossible nowadays. If you add a unique salt for each password, an attacker would have to build a rainbow-table for each password. If you are interested in more information you can have a look at my [tutorial](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php) about safely storing passwords.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the detail in your answer!

Comment: What do you mean by 20+ password? Characters long? Bytes? I do generate random passwords though.

Comment: I just found out I can only use PHP 5.2

Comment: So, I don't know what to do now. I just stick with this until I find a viable option for me.

Comment: @MasonH.Hatfield - With 20+ passwords i meant, that nowadays it is possible to brute-force passwords at a speed of about [8Giga per second](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/#performance) with an unsafe MD5 hash (BCrypt will need much longer). Passwords with a length of 20 characters would therefore need about 10000000000000000000000000000 years to crack. Are you really really stuck with PHP 5.2, BCrypt is supported not before 5.3? If you cannot switch to 5.3 your best bet will probably be the [phpass library](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/).

Comment: Yes, unfortunately yes I'm stuck with PHP 5.2 for the time being. I have been trying to use BCRYPT and tried SCRYPT, but not supported in my version. Currently using salted sha512 passwords.

Comment: i tried password_hash(), it threw the error undefined function. Yes, I have looked into PHPAss, I do believe that's what I'll use.

Answer (score 0):

`password_hash()` generates its own salt. No need to salt again.See this from the [PHP Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php): *If omitted, a random salt will be generated by password_hash() for each password hashed. This is the intended mode of operation.*